# Why appears [object object] instead of object information?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, element

My code is like this but prints out [object Object]. However, if I put element.name it prints correctly but just one value but I want all of them from the object.

```
$("#ingredientDetails").click(function () {
  var searchQuery = $("input[type = 'text']").val();
  ingredients.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.name === searchQuery) {
      $("#ingInformation").text(element);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Turning an object to string produces `[object Object]` by default. You can use `JSON.stringify` if you want to serialise it into a JSON representation.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! It works just fine, however, it still appears in this format {"id":2,"name":"carrot","defaultUnit":"}. Do you have any idea why or how I can make it to appear like a plain text?

Comment: What do you expect the plain text to look like?

Comment: I was thinking without the "{" and ' " '. Just id:2. name:carrot and to have them one below each as atm it's a long line

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line

```
$("#ingInformation").text(element);
```

JQuery's .trim() method [expects something with a data type of String, Number or Boolean](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-text). In this case `element` has a data type of Object. JavaScript tries to convert it from Object to String, which results in "[object] [Object]".

Try using element.value or element.innerText instead, depending on what type of DOM element it is.